# How to pair up two lists?

Tags: python, list

I'm a bit of a Python beginner so I apologise if this is a very basic question.

I have two lists of data which are obtained from:

```
with filein as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        xs, ys = zip(*reader)
```

I would like to create a loop which would take the first item in "xs" and the first item in "ys" and print them out. I would then like to loop back and repeat for the second item in both lists and so forth.

I had thought something like:

```
for x in xs and y in ys:
```

Or

```
for x in xs:
    for y in ys:
```

But neither of these seems to give the desired result.

Answer (score 15):

Use the `zip` function, along with tuple unpacking:

```
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    print x, y
```

In your case, depending on what you need the `xs` and `ys` for, you could have iterated through the `csv.reader` directly:

```
with filein as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for x, y in reader:
        print x, y
```

The `zip(xs, ys)` line was effectively reversing your `xs, ys = zip(*reader)` line.

Answer (score 8):

Use [zip](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip):

```
>>> L=[1,2,3]
>>> M=[4,5,6]
>>> for a,b in zip(L,M):
...   print(a,b)
...
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Answer (score 1):

For a one line you can use combination of `map()` and `lambda()`. [Look here if not familiar to this concepts.](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html)

But be careful, you must be with python 3.x so that print is a function and can be used inside the lambda expression.

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> l1 = [2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [6,7,3,8]
>>> list(map(lambda X: print(X[0],X[1]), list(zip(l1,l2))))
```

output

```
2 6
3 7
4 3
5 8
```

Comment: Not sure why this one was down voted, if its because the print statement is confusing them then use. list(map(lambda x: x, list(zip(l1,l2))))

Comment: To me it appears like OP is asking for all possible combinations rather than aligned pairs produced by yield.